# How to change the value of a node when a specific frame is reached

Tags: animation, geometry-nodes, keyframes

I'm trying to figure out how to insert a keyframe that'll record a change in my geometry nodes' values.

I have a node that controls the starting position of an object, I want the Z-axis to be at `-1.21` for 216 frames, and after that I want to change it to `9.49` until the end of the animation, to create the illusion of an explosion. What happens is that it just stays at 9.49 for the whole animation. So basically -

how can I change the value of a node (float) when a condition is met?

I need some node setup to act as my "if...else..."

[image: on frames 1-215]

[image: on frames 216-until the end]

Comment: Maybe use _Math>Greater Than_ or _Math>Less Than_?

Comment: @ChristopherBennett gonna take a look and try, thanks for the suggestion

Comment: I was able to use the node to output `0` until the frame count reaches 216, question is, how can I switch between values depending on that `1` or `0` that the _Math>Greater Than_ node outputs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To time certain actions in *Geometry Nodes*, you use the `Scene Time` node.

In this example I set the *Z-position* of the object from frame $216$ to the value $9.49$:

[image]

Comment: thank you so much for the great solution!
I just wanna ask - my `Greater Than` node looks a little different; instead of _A_ and _B_ I have a _Value_ and a _Threshold_, I also can't specify I want an _Integer_. how come yours is different from mine?

Comment: @kfirezer You are welcome! On the one hand there is the option *Greater Than* in the `Math` node, but on the other hand there is also the node `Compare`, which I use here. But they both do largely the same thing in this case.